# Can I range over a struct that is just a []struct?

Tags: go

I have some structs that are defined as follows:

```
type Thing struct {
        Name string
}

type ThingList []Thing
```

I am trying to range over `ThingList` as follows:

```
thingList := GetThingListFilledWithValues()
for _, v := range thingList {
        v.DoStuffToThing()
}
```

It throws an error saying that you can't range over `thingList` because it's not a slice, but a `type ThingList`.

How can I range over `type ThingList` knowing that at it's root, it's a slice?

**EDIT**:
So apparently, I wasn't fully correct in my post here. Instead of `type ThingList` being incorrect, it was a `type *ThingList` that I was trying to range over, which it failed on. So you **can** range over a listStruct with type `[]Struct`, just not a `*listStruct`.

Thanks for helping me find the answer, everybody.

Comment: I changed one mistake in your `for` and the other parts of the code look correct, check in https://play.golang.org/p/ydjoKEgvlX , if the problem persists, maybe you can add some more context about your code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use an instance of your new type as the return from your function. You must be returning the wrong thing from `GetThingListFilledWithValues()`

For example:

```
func GetThingListFilledWithValues() ThingList {
    return ThingList{
        Thing{Name: "One"},
        Thing{Name: "Two"},
    }
}
```

And use it like so

```
thingList := GetThingListFilledWithValues()
for _, v := range thingList {
    v.DoStuffToThing()
}
```

Here's the full example in the go playground https://play.golang.org/p/6lGdbBsQgJ

Comment: If you had another attribute on ThingList like a name, would it still be iterable?

Comment: @aeros Yep, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @aeros there's no way to do that. It's a slice, it doesn't have fields.

Comment: See my update to my question above. And thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @hobbs that's what I figured, as soon as you make it a struct it's non-iterable